# How to keep custom navigation properties after a model rebuild?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I have several navigation properties from a 'Users' table to a 'Reports' table. The navigation properties that are generated are obviously accessed like this:

```
USER.REPORTs.Where(x => ...)
USER.REPORTs2.Where(x => ...)
USER.REPORTs3.Where(x => ...)
```

The first one is user createdId, second UserApprovedId etc... basic stuff.

These are extremely difficult to interpret. Its difficult to tell which property you are navigating without accessing the EDMX and checking the navigation property.

Now I know I can create my own End1/End2 navigation properties the properties manager but these are lost if the Model is recreated.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Would u please add more information to understand the problem clearly, hopefully then I can add some help here?

Comment: It's not related to MVC it's absolutely EF issue !.

Comment: How are you recreating model? If you are only updating from database, then names will not change. You can rename navigational properties as you like, and access them in code by that name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tried this, but here's an idea: since all the entity types are partial classes why not wrap the navigation property generated by Visual Studio in another property with a convenient name?

In your designer file you'll have something like this:

```
public partial class MyEntity : EntityObject
{
    #region Navigation Properties
    public EntityCollection<MyOtherEntity> Other_Entities1
    {
        // ...
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You can then create another file in which to wrap the navigation property:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public EntityCollection<MyOtherEntity> OtherEntities
    {
        get { return Other_Entities1;}
    }
}
```

You'll use the property above throughout your code and since the same logic is used when Visual Studio generates the `.edmx` file the wrapped property won't change.
Even if the wrapped property will change its name you'll need to adjust the code in a single place.

Comment: That seems to work at first but the wrapping properties cannot be used in Linq to Entities...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your problem correctly, but it sounds like you just want a "cleaner" way to access the results of a REPORTs.Where(...) LINQ query directly from the USER object. If that is the case, I suggest creating extensions of the USER object like this:

```
public static class UserExtensions
{
 public static List<REPORT> ReportsWithSomeCondition(this USER user)
 {
    return user.REPORTs.Where(...).ToList();
 }
}
```

And the way you can cleanly call this is:

```
List<REPORT> results = USER.ReportsWithSomeCondition()
```

If I totally missed the point, please clarify your question and I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have the same problem as i understand from your question.

**You want to keep your navigational properties names as clear as you can but whenever recreate your Model from edmx ?!.**

Actually i hope if there is a better solution but here what I'm doing :

1. Name your relations in DataBase a good names like : `FK_Users_CreateUserReport`, `FK_Users_ApprovedUserReport` ... or any suitable names we'll then rename the navigational properties as `ApprovedUserReport` and `CreateUserReport` so on ...
2. make a helper code to execute whenever you recreate your Model and this code will open your edmx file and makes update to all navigational properties you want something like this:

   ```
   // file here is the path to your edmx file
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
   {
       var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm");
       var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
       var list = (from xElem in doc.Descendants(ns + "NavigationProperty")
                   where xElem.Attribute("Name").Value.StartsWith("REPORTs"))
                   select xElem).ToList();
       foreach (var item in list)
       {
           var newName = item.Attribute("Relationship").Value.Split('_').LastOrDefault();
           if (!newName.Contains("."))
               item.SetAttributeValue("Name", newName);
           else
           {
               var ss = newName.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
           }
       }
       doc.Save(file);
       MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());
   }
   ```

Final thing if you used Code Only pattern then this problem is gone but in that case you should keep your Model in agreement with your DataBase by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your custom entity code in separate code files using the partial class mechanism. This allows the generated code to be generated without your custom code to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Wahid's answer seems to be the best one for long term maintenance. We considered implementing interface properties in the Partial Class we use as a "Buddy Class" for extensions and setting up Metadata linking. But then the properties in the T4 template we are Interfacing would still be public and they should be private.

To improve upon Wahid's suggestion; we chose to instead of changing the standard of how we name Foreign key relationships, extend them.

FK_Users_Report_CreateUserReport would actually be our solution. The standard naming convention for the first 2 values is maintained and in the update model code you can force it to only change the navigation property names of ones with the 3rd underscore and 3rd value on it. Ensuring you do no effect anyone other navigation property names if they didn't follow the standard naming convention for Foreign Keys in the DB.